# Specifying format parameter in PHP youTubeAPI

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am using google-api-php-client to search youtube. What I want to do is specify format=5 to filter embedable videos.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $searchStr,
  'maxResults' => $maxResultsNum,
));
foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
}
```

How do I specify the format=5 so it can be played in iPhone. The documentation has no reference on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter you are looking for is [videoSyndicated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated)

your call will look like

$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $searchStr,
  'maxResults' => $maxResultsNum,
  'videoSyndicated' => true,
  'type' =>true
));

Comment: Not sure what is going on, 'videoSyndicated' => true returned zero results. I am using youtube API v3. Does that make any difference ?

Comment: Edited answer, you need to specify type = video to be able to use videoSyndicated.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help. Now I get some results. But not sure if I got the correct one. For example Video Id 2USKtCmkxJQ returned by videoSyndicated=>true. But inside iPhone App when I load it using iframe I get eventData=150. Do you know what is going on ?

Comment: Great, feel free to tag this answer as right solution and vote up.